# Facebook read_stream permission submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got problem about read_stream permission.

What mean "Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available."?

[image: error submission]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you can use it if you are doing a Facebook app replicate on a platform where there is no Facebook app. So for example if you created a new mobile phone you can create a Facebook app for it.

Comment: So no way if we create app for web! Damn

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the 'read_stream' permission granted on Android. The only thing I imagine that could work is to request the 'user_posts' permission, which will only include the user's own posts.